# Have a project that requires nested dictonaries and I have it almost working, but continue to get a index error

Tags: python, python-3.x

```
k = 2

source = 'aaabaaacaaadaaabaaabaaac'

dictonary = {}

for x in range(len(source)):
    if source[x:x+k] in dictonary.keys() and source[x+k] == dictonary[source[x:x+k][x+k]]:
        dictonary[source[x:x+k][x+k]] += 1
    elif source[x:x+k] in dictonary.keys():
        dictonary[source[x:x+k]].update({source[x+k] : 1})
    else:
        dictonary[source[x:x+k]] = {source[x+k] : 1}
```

End goal is trying to create a nested dictionary that looks like:

```
{'aa': {'a': 6, 'b': 3, 'c': 2, 'd': 1}, 'ab': {'a': 3}, 'ba': {'a': 3},
 'ac': {'a': 1, '': 1}, 'ca': {'a': 1}, 'ad': {'a': 1}, 'da': {'a': 1}}
```

where if a the same character comes after the n-gram its added to the second dictionary value

Ex: 'aaa' would add 1 to the second dictionary value of 'aa' 'a' + 1

Most of the loop works properly just having trouble with incrementing the second dictionary values, I thought what I had would work but having trouble referencing that value, checking if its equal and then adding 1 if it is.

Suggested solutions are helpful but if someone could explain why Im getting a index error that would be much appreciated. 
IndexError: string index out of range

Answer (score 0):

The simplest and easiest solution that comes to my mind would be to simply loop through all n-grams and count on the way.

```
result = {}
for i in range(len(source)-k):
    ngram = source[i:i+k]
    if ngram not in r:
        r[ngram] = {}

    after = source[i+k]
    if after not in r[ngram]
        r[ngram][after] = 0
    r[ngram][after] += 1

print(result)
```

Answer (score 0):

Go through the string in trigraphs and count the digraphs `x+y` and following letters `z`:

```
count = {}
for x,y,z in zip(source, source[1:], source[2:]):
    if x + y not in count: count[x + y] = {}
    if z not in count[x + y]: count[x + y][z] = 0
    count[x + y][z] += 1

count
#{'aa': {'a': 6, 'b': 3, 'c': 2, 'd': 1}, 'ab': {'a': 3},
# 'ba': {'a': 3}, 'ac': {'a': 1}, 'ca': {'a': 1}, 
# 'ad': {'a': 1}, 'da': {'a': 1}}
```

Note: This solution works only for k=2.